# Glassfish 4 take long time to deploy

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have Glassfish 4.0, on windows 7 and netbeans 8
when I try to deploy java EE application, sometimes the deploy time takes 2-3 seconds, and sometimes it lasts forever!!!!

I have to kill the java.exe from the task manager in order to make it work again, sometimes this solution does not success and I have to restart my PC.

I tried to remove the glassfish from netbeans and adding it again, but with no result,
I tried to change the windows to XP, with no result,
I tried to change the whole PC with no result also....

I am still having this problem and I cant go on LIVE server if I cant fix this on the development machine.

please any advice?

Comment: any help here please

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by creating new project, then I put the "web" and "src" folder from my old project.
the glass fish now deploy fast.
I found the cause for this, its that I work with a team and we share the same build files from our different PCs, so after removing the build files everything work good.
it happened because we use SVN to share the code.